# What are these spots that appear after using subsurf modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I added a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, *Creased* some edges to *1.00* and some white spots appeared. I've never seen that before. Is something wrong with the UV shading?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's the base mesh representation intersecting with the modified mesh representation. Try grabbing a vertex near there and moving it in and out.

Answer (score 6):

It simply means that the subsurf is generating mesh outside the bounds of the non-subsurfed mesh. It's not an issue and they will not show as soon as you <kbd>Tab</kbd> back to *Object Mode*.